# Preserving white spaces in inline listings

Tags: spacing, listings

Is there any way of preserving white spaces in \lstinlne{}?

Comment: Usually they are preserved, so please add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), that shows the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Preserving spaces it the usual behavior of `\lstinline`, so you have nothing else to do but not changing the default behavior:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinline{Which spaces     do you mean?}
\end{document}
```

results in

[image: spaces are preserved]

Note: You should not use `\lstinline` inside the arguments of other commands, because the tokens are already build by reading the argument of the topmost command. See the [`listings` manual, section 6.1](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf#subsection.6.1) for more information about using listings inside the argument of another command.

However, color for inline listings can be done, e.g., using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}
\begin{document}
\lstinline{Which spaces     do you mean?}

Colors in inline listings do work with:
\lstinline[basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{red}]|red listing   with spaces| 
or {\color{red}\lstinline|red listing   with spaces|}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem was that I used it inside text color: `\textcolor{red}{\lstinline{aaa     bbb}}`

Comment: @Mihai Now you should know, why you always should add a minimal but working example to your questions! Please add one to your question as asked 25 minutes after you have posted the question month ago!